# How to update data dynamically in my case?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular Framework in my app.

I have a setup like this

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.controller').
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test', {
                templateUrl: 'template/main.html',
                controller: 'mCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/te'});
    }]);
```

test-controller.js

```
   var controllers = angular.module('myApp.controller', ['ui.bootstrap']).
    controller('mCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       ..other codess....
       //get data after a click....
       $scope.clickme = function(){
           $scope.mainData = data //getting new data after an click event is fired   
           //broadcast broadcastData event
           $scope.$broadcast('broadcastData', $scope);
        }
    }]).
    controller('NCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       $scope.test = 'test data here'

       //getting data from broadcastData event 
       $scope.$on('broadcastData', function(event, Data){
           $scope.test = Data.test //Data.test is a string called 'after click'
       })      
}]);
```

index.html

```
    <div ng-controller='mCtrl'> 
      <div ng-click='clickme()'> click me</div>
      <ng-include src="'template/main.html'"></ng-include>
   </div>
```

main.html

```
<div ng-controller='NCtrl'>
    {{mainData}}
/div>
```

My problem is that `mainData` shows '`test data here`' fine when the page first loaded. However, after I click the div and fire the click event. The mainData doesn't update to '`after click`'. It seems the `$scope.$on` doesn't update the html `mainData`...I have spent much time on this issue. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: please show where `data` is defined in your `mCtrl`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to broadcast using `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` from `mCtrl` because `broadcast` dispatches the event name **downwards** to all child scopes.

And I don't think using [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) will create a child scope off of the controller's scope. It creates a new scope by itself making it a sibling of `mCtrl's` scope.